# Where is my steam folder?

Tags: steam

I see the error "Failed to Start Game (Missing Executable)" when launching a game through Steam.

the steam help tells me to do this:

```
Completely exit Steam.
Navigate to your Steam installation folder (~C:\Program Files\Steam). 
Delete the 'appcache' folder.
Restart your computer and attempt to launch the game through Steam.
```

but i cant find the folder.
I use ubuntu 12.04
can any 1 help?

Comment: /home/username/.local/share/Steam

Comment: Seems like you installed Steam through Wine. You should install the native Linux version.

Comment: i installed using ubuntu software centre